# autoupdate module in IPython / jupyter notebook

Tags: python, import, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I wrote my own module which as the following structure:

```
mymodule/
├── __init__.py
├── part1.py
├── part2.py
├── part3.py
└── part4.py
```

To test my module I am using IPython and/or jupyter notebook (formerly Ipython Notebook). As usual I do the module import like

```
import mymodule
```

Let's say I edit some code in `part2.py` and want to use the updated version of my module. First I thought just re-importing the module by `import mymodule` would do the job, but it does not. To completely reload the module I have to close IPython's shell or restart jupyter's kernel and start again by importing `mymodule`.

However, reffering to the [docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/extensions/autoreload.html), IPython provides an auto-update function called `autoreload` which provides different modes and could be activated as follows:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 1
%aimport mymodule
```

Using both of my snippets, I am importing `mymodule` like that:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 1
%aimport mymodule

import mymodule

# let's do something with the module here
```

However, even with activated `autoreload 1` or `autoreload 2` neither IPython nor jupyter are doing what I expect them to do and I still have to quit IPython's shell or restart jupyter's kernel in order to use the edited code of `part2.py` which is part of `mymodule`.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that I did not get the point about how this should work.

Comment: sounds like a bug, I use `%autoreload 2` (actually I add it to `ipython_config.py`) and it works for most of cases. Only multiple inheritance is troublesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `%autoreload 1` to `%autoreload 2` like dashesy said, old version or bug.